# Hexadecimal representations of a floating number in c language

Tags: c, floating-point

Suppose, `float a = 12.5;`

I know its hexadecimal representation is `0×41480000`.But how can I print its hexadecimal representation from `float` through a program?

Comment: You know its hex representation is 0x4148000 *on your machine*.  It might be a whole other value on an old Mac, or an ARM machine, etc.

Comment: @cHao: It'll be the same on any system that uses IEEE 754 single-precision floats. That isn't *all* systems, but it's many of them, including practically everything recent. (Including both old Macs and ARM machines.)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: … to be more clear, all Macs since 1984 and ARM machines since they existed have used IEEE 754. If you simply want to serialize floats without loss of precision, check out the `%H` printf format specifier.

Comment: printf does support %H format specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable way to do this in C is to use a union. In C 1999 or later, you can do this with this expression:

```
(union { float f; uint32_t u; }) { a } .u
```

A complete demonstration program is below. This requires that `float` be the IEEE-754 32-bit binary in the interchange format, which is common in modern C implementations.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    float a = 12.5;
    printf("%" PRIx32 "\n",
        (union { float f; uint32_t u; }) { a } .u);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use type punning with a pointer to treat the float as an integer.

```
float a = 12.5;
long *aint = (long *)&a;
printf("0x%lx\n", *aint);
```

You can also do it with just casts, rather than adding a variable:

```
printf("0x%lx\n", *(long *)&a);
```

Comment: you need typecast here  `long *aint = &a;`

Comment: Better to use `uint32_t` which is guaranteed to be the expected size… and it's more type punning *through* a pointer than *with* a pointer, i.e. `printf( "%p" )`.

Comment: Type punning through pointers like that can lead to undefined behavior e.g because of alignment problems, so this isn't really a good advice. If you'd have to do such things, use a `union` around the two types that you are interested int.

Comment: @JensGustedt of course it's undefined behavior. It's inherently unportable, but it works on most real machines.

Comment: @Barmar: Code written in C depends on the C implementation, not solely on the underlying hardware. Optimization, especially when the compiler is permitted to assume strict aliasing rules, may break code that refers to data through pointers converted from their original type. In contrast, accessing a union member other than the last one stored **is** explicitly supported by the C standard, subject to certain constraints. Also, “type punning” refers to accessing a union member other than the last one stored, not to access through a converted pointer.

Comment: This code also fails if `long` is a different size than `float`. Also, the `long` type does not match the `x` specifier used in the `printf`, so the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Since C99 there is the `%a` specifier that does basically that. It gives you a representation of the mantissa in hex and the exponent. The only obstacle here is that it does it for `double` instead of `float`, but that shouldn't bother you much.